# sqlite3.OperationalError: wrong number of arguments to function

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm stuck on this error running the script below which goes through each column in my table and returns the max price for each. n.b. I've shortened the amount columns for this question.

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = 'foo.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
column = ['AAC', 'AAD', 'ABC', 'ABP', 
          'AGL', 'AHG', 'AHY', 'AIO', 
          'ALL', 'ALQ', 'ALU', 'AMC']
for i in range(len(column)):
    c.execute("SELECT max(%s) FROM prices" % (column[i]))
    print (column[i], c.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

The script prints 8 results then I get the error?

Output:

```
AAC [('1.495',)]
AAD [('2.50',)]
ABC [('4.455',)]
ABP [('2.98',)]
AGL [('16.86',)]
AHG [('4.25',)]
AHY [('1.70',)]
AIO [('8.75',)]
sqlite3.OperationalError: wrong number of arguments to function max()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALL` is a keyword in SQLite. (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

You need to quote it to make your query run correctly (see the link above).

Comment: Thank you @Szymon I would've been stuck on that for hours. I used `c.execute("SELECT max("'"%s"'") FROM prices" % (columns[i]))`